# Is it ok to advertise an otherwise wasted bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty, etiquette

I asked a question a few days back. No one answered, so I put up a 50-point bounty. A day or two after that, I found an answer and answered my own question. No one else has answered.

I do not expect to get my bounty back, but is it considered bad etiquette to somehow advertise the fact that there's basically 50 bounty floating around for free to anyone who'd take it?

(Note: If it is, sorry for this post, which sort of inadvertently does just that.)

Comment: Depends on the "somehow". No one would mind if you took to the chatroom, fb, twitter, etc.

Comment: At least link us to the question!

Comment: @JorgeCastro Ah. I didn't want to link to the question in case the answer was "No, it's not ok."

But the bounty's been given already. :)